# ROSARIA installing on fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys!
I'm having problem installing ROSARIA on fuerte.
Following tutorial *How to use ROSARIA* I tried

`roslocate info ROSARIA | rosws merge -`
but it doesn't work, so I downloaded ROSARIA with `rosws set amor-ros-pkg https ... --hg`.

Then I followed the tutorial steps, but `rosmake ROSARIA` had the following output

`[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ROSARIA [ make ] [rosmake-0] Finished <<< ROSARIA ROS_NOBUILD in package ROSARIA No Makefile in package ROSARIA [ rosmake ] Results:    [ rosmake ] Built 1 packages with 0 failures.`

So I guess I downloaded version for groovy?

How can I fix this and install ROSARIA on fuerte?

Thanks in advance! Any help appreciated!

Greets,
da-na

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57690/rosaria-installing-on-fuerte/) by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-03-19**:
Does 'rospack find rosaria' show the correct path?

**Comment by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on 2013-03-19**:
it doesn't. As I understand there's no way for "rospack find rosaria" to show it, cause there's no manifest.xml in rosaria folder

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-03-19**:
And what about using catkin_make on your top workspace? CmakeLists.txt seems like catkin format...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a bunch of flux around ROSARIA right now, sorry for the mess...

Try this:
rosws set amor-ros-pkg https://code.google.com/p/amor-ros-pkg/ --hg -v fuerte

If you wouldn't mind, please update the wiki if it works for you so the next person will not get stuck too. :)
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on 2013-03-19**:
thank you Dereck!

it worked for me, and since I have compiled rosaria, now I'll try to use it with PeopleBot ^^

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2013-03-20**:
I updated the wiki page with this info, thanks Dereck!